# Avro array default is null and not an empty array

Tags: java, avro

I have the following in my Avro schema (user.avsc):

```
{
    "name": "properties",
     "type": {
        "type": "array",
         "items": "long"
    },
    "default": []
}
```

I would expect that the array would default to an empty array `[]`, but when I run my tests it defaults to `null`. I am using the generated `Builder.build()` to create an instance of my `User` class without setting this field (so it will use the default). Why would this not default to `[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Defaults are for deserialization when the field doesn't exist, not for serialization

As written in the spec

> `default`: A default value for this field, **only used when *reading instances that lack the field*** for schema evolution purposes. The presence of a default value **does not make the field optional at encoding time**